# How to ignore the actual value of argument passed into the function under test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints) to do unit testing in my iOS project.

I simply want to verify that a function is invoked **without concerning what is the argument value** passed in.

For example, I want to verify the following function is invoked:

```
[school startTime:currentTime];
```

(Short note: the funcition in School class `-(void)startTime:(long long)` takes a `long long` type parameter)

In my test case I tried:

```
OCMVerify([schoolMock startTime:(long long)[OCMArg any]]);
```

I am pretty sure the code under test has been invoked, but I get error:
 `OCMockObject(School):Method startTime:2005634354 was not invoked`.

It looks like OCMock is still verifying the exact value of argument passed into the function. **WHY?**

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `startTime:` method to make sure it's being called.

Comment: @stevekohls, did that, it is being called.

Comment: When you hit the breakpoint, log the calling instance to verify that it is a mock and not a real implementation.

Comment: @KyleParent , I did that, it does run on the mocked instance.

Comment: Can you share your test and any relevant implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Your cast from `[OCMArg any]` to a type `(long long)` is converts the `OCMock` object to the value 2005634354, which is why the test expects that as the parameter. `startTime` is expecting a non-object argument, which is not supported for `[OCMArg any]`. If you remove the cast to `long long` you would probably get a compiler warning.

Instead, change your verification to this:

```
OCMVerify([[schoolMock ignoringNonObjectArgs] startTime:0]);
```

`ignoringNonObjectArgs` will do just as the name implies: the non-object argument expected by `startTime` will be entirely ignored. I usually use 0 to have a consistent and not confusing placeholder value, but in theory you could put any `long long` you want in the verify, and as long as the method is called by your mock object this will pass.

Comment: I tried your answer, but I now get error `Method startTime:0 was not invoked`. I added a breakpoint on this line of code, I am sure it is calling on the mocked school instance.

Answer (score 0):

The OCMock documentation is pretty clear about this, I think: "Arguments that are neither objects nor pointers or selectors cannot be ignored using an any placeholder." ([Section 4.1](http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints)).